# Sonar Runner not picking up the report xml file in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, sonar-runner

[Sonar Runner step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCa2s.png)We are trying to setup Sonar for a project(Modules) in TeamCity. We have the following build steps:
1) Nuget Install
2) Visual Studio sln
3) Inspections(.Net)
4) Sonar Runner

In the Sonar Runner step,it is unable to get hold of that file.see image 2
[unable to find that xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo11k.png)

Please help by pointing me in the right direction on how to make it pick the xml file.

Comment: Can you show the full log for the step, from starting SQR? Would be nice to see what it's initialising the values to before the error, e.g. -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Data\TeamCityAgent01\temp\buildTmp, but all of them will be useful to try and diagnose this. Is the runner using the DEFAULT JDK path?

Comment: it is using the default jdk path. I have included the sonar runner step log in my post(description:Sonar Runner Step)

Answer (score 3):

The main trick here is to pass report XML to SonarQube runner - it could be done with `/output` resharper option (see step #2 below). There are though some more things which could ruin your day so I composed a full procedure.

1. First of all make sure that SonarQube Server is configured correctly to accept Resharper data. You'll need installed Resharper and C# plugins and configured Quality Profile with Resharper rules. To check configuration I recommend running analysis manually as described in the [Resharper plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/ReSharper+Plugin).
2. Then configure your Inspections(.Net) TeamCity build step to create report XML in a well-known place: open advanced options and in the field "Additional inspectCode.exe arguments:" add `/output=%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\inspectReport.xml` (or any other location). **Important!** The step will fail because it expects the report in default location (see [issue on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45795)). All subsequent steps will need `Execute step: if some of the previous steps failed` option to run
3. In SonarQube Runner step open advanced options and to the "Additional parameters:" field add this 2 lines (replace `pathToSolutionFile` with real path):

   ```
   -Dsonar.resharper.cs.reportPath=%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\inspectReport.xml
   -Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile=pathToSolutionFile
   ```
4. Finally to see the inspections report in TeamCity UI as well add a new Command Line build step with:

   ```
   echo "##teamcity[importData path='%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\inspect.xml' type='ReSharperInspectCode']"
   ```

Comment: Hi linfar....thank you for the reply, it worked. Now i have a new problem, we recently upgraded to TeamCity 10 and i find the same problem here again....i replicated everything as it is but of no use....can you please help me

Comment: Make sure you've updated the plugin to the [latest version](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildId=836043&buildTypeId=TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_TeamCitySonarQubePlugin_Build100x&tab=artifacts).
Second - the issue I've mentioned is already fixed so step 4 and `Execute step: if some of the previous steps failed` options aren't needed now.
If you'll still have problems I can help you on [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/TeamCity.SonarQubePlugin/issues)